# Stellar Federation Address "not found or invalid"

Tags: accounts, federation

I've set up a stellar.toml for my federation server and implemented the federation API endpoint as documented here https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/federation.html. The only purpose of the server is to translate vanity addresses to public keys + text memos.

When I try to send XLM to user*myproduct.com however, Stellar account viewer tells me: "Stellar address cannot be found or is invalid."

I'm fairly confident that the stellar.toml file and the federation endpoint therein are implemented correctly and publicly accessible.

How can I debug this? What's the best way to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have server logs to see if it's making the query at all?

Comment: I don't because I'm using https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer trying to send the XLM. But now that you mentioned it I inspected the console and there was the solution! An HTTP forwarding/CORS problem :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a Federation query yourself: https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/FederationServer.html#.resolve

And seeing whether it works or not.

```
StellarSdk.FederationServer.resolve('bob*stellar.org')
 .then(federationRecord => {
   // {
   //   account_id: 'GB5XVAABEQMY63WTHDQ5RXADGYF345VWMNPTN2GFUDZT57D57ZQTJ7PS',
   //   memo_type: 'id',
   //   memo: 100
   // }
 })
 .catch(err => console.error(err));
```